# Laravel HTTPS routes

Tags: php, laravel-5

today I decided to move my website to HTTPS. Early my website work on HTTP.

My problem is in misunderstood how Laravel pass HTTP and https in helpers function `route('name')`

I change my website URL in `config/app.php` to `https://www.domain.name` and I think, this solution helps me. But I got a strange result.

In `php artisan tinker` if I pass `route('ROUTE.NAME')` I got right link `https://www.domain.name/route/path`
but in blade template I got `http://www.domain.name/route/path`

The same situation with `\URL::to('/')`

Maybe someone can explain to me why this happened?

Comment: What is written exactly in your `config/app.php`? Could it be that another url is defined in the `.env` file in the root and `env()` is loading it?

Comment: Are you visiting the site in the browser using `http` or `https`?

Comment: @UfguFugullu in .env I pass https://www.domain.name and in config/app.php too

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski I redirect users via NGINX to https www by default

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The @dekts response is correct, but the "*right*" place to put this kind of stuff is the "*app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php*" on the **boot** method.

```
//file: app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot()
    {
        if (app()->environment('remote')) {
            URL::forceScheme('https');
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

You can also add a new variable on your "*.env*" file, something like:

```
#file: .env
FORCE_HTTPS=true
```

And change the condition to

```
//file: app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
public function boot()
{
    if(env('FORCE_HTTPS',false)) { // Default value should be false for local server
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```

Hope this help.

edit: corrected `forceSchema` to `forceScheme` as noted on the comments. ;)

Comment: should be:
URL::forceScheme('https');

Comment: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;` is not needed if you use `url()->forceSchema('https');`

Comment: `Scheme` not `Schema`

Comment: URL::forceScheme('https'); still works on Laravel 7.

Answer (score 8):

I struggled with this for ages. My solution was to put the following in my routes.php file (you may prefer a different place for it)

I have also wrapped a conditional statement around this line, so it only applies to my remote configuration:

```
if (App::environment('remote')) {
    URL::forceSchema('https');
}
```

You can try to add in your AppServiceProvider in the `boot` method.
here: `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

Or another way:

So I figured it out. It not that easy but in your `AppServiceProvider.php` you must add: `$this->app['request']->server->set('HTTPS', true);` in `register` method. And that is how I figured it out.

Btw. Setting `APP_URL` does nothing to `HTTP` side of your app, it's for artisan.

PS. CloudFlare `HTTPS` Rewrites are also good idea :)

Answer (score 7):

in .env file

```
FORCE_HTTPS=true
```

in  app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    if(env('FORCE_HTTPS',false)) { 
        URL::forceScheme('https');
    }
}
```

**After 5.4** the method name is **forceScheme**

if you use '**forceSchema**' will get an error

```
"Method Illuminate\Routing\UrlGenerator::forceSchema does not exist."
```

Answer (score 6):

Automatic detection http/https

```
<?php
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
      /* Use https links instead http links */
      if (Request::server('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO') == 'https')
      {
         URL::forceScheme('https');
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.env file

```
FORCE_HTTPS=true
```

app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
```

```
if (app()->environment('remote') || env('FORCE_HTTPS',false)) {
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```