# The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST, but it's POST method. - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need help. When I fill in the form and go to the POST method I get an error on the link **The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.** But i use POST method in form and in route. How do I fix this?

This is my code in **index.blade.php**

```
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                                      Add Hotel
                                    </button>
                                    
                                    
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                                      <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                                        <div class="modal-content">
                                          <div class="modal-header">
                                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Add Hotel</h5>
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form class="form" action="{{ route('hotel.create.fusr') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                                            @csrf
                                         <div class="media">
                                                <!-- upload and reset button -->
                                                <div class="media-body mt-75 ml-1">
                                                    <h5>LOGO</h5>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="custom-file">
                                                        <input type="file" name="logo" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" accept="image/*" />
                                                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">ფაილის არჩევა</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                                                    <br>
                                                    <br>
                                                    <p>allowed JPG, GIF or PNG.</p>    
                                                 </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--/ upload and reset button -->
                                            </div>
                                            <br>
                                            <div class="media">
                                                <!-- upload and reset button -->
                                                <div class="media-body mt-75 ml-1">
                                                    <h5>background</h5>
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="custom-file">
                                                        <input type="file" name="background" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" accept="image/*" />
                                                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">ფაილის არჩევა</label>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                                                    <br>
                                                    <br>
                                                    <p>allowed JPG, GIF or PNG.</p>  
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--/ upload and reset button -->
                                            </div>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="title">სასტუმროს სახელი</label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="title" class="form-control" placeholder="სასტუმროს სახელი" name="name" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>                                                
                                            <div class="col">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="school_creating">Hotel description</label>
                                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="school_creating" placeholder="Write your hotel description" name="description">
                                                                
                                                    </textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            ...
                                            <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="map">Google map</label>
                                                    <textarea type="text" id="map" class="form-control" name="map" placeholder="iframe" /></textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                           </div>
                                          </div>
                                          <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Hotel</button>
                                          </div>
                                         </form>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
```

This is my code in **web.php**

```
      Route::post('user/dashboard/hotels/create', 'App\Http\Controllers\HotelsController@create_user')->name('hotel.create.fusr')->middleware(['auth', 'active_user']);
```

This is my code in **HotelsController**

```
   public function create_user(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|unique:hotels|max:255',
            'logo' => 'required',
            'background' => 'required',
            'status' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required|unique:hotels',
            'email' => 'required|unique:hotels|max:255',
            'phone' => 'required|unique:hotels|max:255',
            'price' => 'required|max:255',
            'description' => 'required|min:60',
            'service' => 'required|min:60',
        ]);

        $hotel = new Hotels;
        $hotel->name = $request->name;
        $hotel->description = $request->description;
        $hotel->service_description = $request->service;
        $hotel->slug = str_slug($hotel->name, "-");
        $hotel->status = '2';
        $hotel->address = $request->address;
        $hotel->region = $request->region;
        $hotel->country = $request->country;
        $hotel->preprice = $request->preprice;
        $hotel->price_per_day_person = $request->price;
        $hotel->city_or_state = $request->city;
        $hotel->website = $request->website;
        $hotel->twitter = $request->twitter;
        $hotel->facebook = $request->facebook;
        $hotel->instagram = $request->insta;
        $hotel->email = $request->email;
        $hotel->phone = $request->phone;
        $hotel->phone_two = $request->phone_two;
        $hotel->google_map = $request->map;
        $hotel->owner_id = auth()->user()->id;
        
        if($request->hasFile('logo')){
            $logo = $request->file('logo');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $logo->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($logo)->save( public_path('/uploads/hotels/' . $filename ) );
        $hotel->logo = $filename;     
        }
        if($request->hasFile('background')){
            $background = $request->file('background');
            $filename = time() . '.' . $background->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($background)->save( public_path('/uploads/hotels/' . $filename ) );
        $hotel->main_photo = $filename;     
        }
        $hotel->save();

        return redirect()->view('success.hotel');
    }
```

I really need help. Thank you.

Comment: Open up your browser's developer console and watch the Network tab to make sure there's no redirect happening. HTTP -> HTTPS is one of the most common culprits of this.

Comment: is it possible that you have the same route name for the get and post route?

Comment: i haven't any other same route. but i i'll try aynber's solution, thanks.

Comment: I believe that `$request->validate()` will redirect to the same route you're on as a `GET` request if validation fails. What is the `Route::get()` that renders this form? You only have this defined as `POST`, so it could be that. Additionally, is `redirect()->view()` valid? I would expect this needs to be `redirect()->route()`, with the name of the route that returns that view.

Comment: Tim, i tried to **redirect()->back()** but it's not working. i also tried to write **GET** method in **web.php**. it's only redirecting back and not adding data in database.

Comment: I also tried **aynber** solution. and it's redirecting HHTP -> HTTPS. if I turn it off there won't be any secure server. how to write **.htaccess** or **middleware** correctly for it?

Comment: If validation fails it will redirect to the same page and might result in what you are seeing as well.

Comment: You can't fix a HTTP -> HTTPS redirection in htaccess or middleware, especially since you don't want to turn off HTTPS. The correct thing to do would be to have all of the routes HTTPS (so they inherit the current protocol), or hard-code the route in your form to use HTTPS instead. I do see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409807/laravel-https-routes/44410300 which tells how to force HTTPS for all routes, which would make sure the GET routes (such as the form page) would be HTTPS so the form action would inherit it.

Comment: Thank you, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

change your @csrf in index.blade.php to

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: Not working, **@csrf** and 
`<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">` are the same. If you write **@csrf** in code, it will show `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="csrf_token_values">` in the site inspect element.

Comment: @B3k4 ...ok i didnt know that...anyway thanks for the info...

Answer (score -2):

there's two options to fix this issue

first
find if there's other route with same name
as
hotel.create.fusr
or same url of this route with diffrent method and delete it

second your route is put method

if same issue still happend

try to change route name and path for this route

and do next steps

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: I've already tried all this solutions but still nothing. maybe I have another route like this, but it's admin.hotel.create